# Who is Moshiach?

Tags: halacha, hashkafah-philosophy, messiah

How do I know that someone is Moshiach? Will I just know? Are there requirements? If someone tells me that he is the Moshiach, is he to be believed. It would seem seem strange to say so.

Comment: Related (about Eliyahu as harbinger): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/59523/472

Answer (score 16):

Here are the Rambam's instructions on how to recognize Moshiach: [Melachim U'Milchamotahem 11](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188356/jewish/Chapter-11.htm)

A Jewish King from the House of David who learns and observes the Torah (written and oral) and  assures that Israel does as well can be presumed to be Moshiach.

If he does so and rebuilds the Beis HaMikdosh and gathers in the exiles he certainly is Moshiach.

Comment: Or, in Hebrew: http://mechon-mamre.org/i/e511n.htm

Comment: Specifically halacha 4 gives pretty clear guidelines. According to it the answer to your last question is most likely 'no', unless you converse with overwhelmingly successful kings of Israel.

Comment: the hebrew is important, since it contains a phrase somehow omitted in the translation, וְנִצַּח כָּל הָאֻמּוֹת שֶׁסְּבִיבָיו

Comment: I think you have things out of order... In fact, R. Kook says specifically, that 'the moshiach' only comes after the exiles have been gathered, based on the Rambam.

Comment: @avi: doesn't that amount to the same thing, though? Once the exiles have been gathered in and the Beis Hamikdash has been rebuilt, then "the Moshiach" comes - i.e., the person who accomplished all of this is acclaimed as Moshiach.

Comment: I thought Cyrus was messiah. The bible explicitly said so. I didn't know he's from a house of David. In fact, cyrus is the only guy in the whole bible ever explicitly declared mosiach by God himself. http://www.cgg.org/index.cfm/fuseaction/Library.sr/CT/PW/k/187/Cyrus-Gods-Anointed.htm I shouldn't trust any other candidate do I?

Comment: @joshwaxman The phrase may be omitted in the translation, because it is omitted in the [printed editions](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=14&hilchos=83&perek=11&halocha=4). The more interesting question to me is why the answerer doesn't mention "and fight(s) the wars of God"( Chabad's interpretation notwithstanding) which is both in the printed editions and in the translation.

Comment: Okay, so Moshiach must be a king. That means Israel can no longer be a democracy then... And how do you know he will be from the house of David? Genetic testing?

Comment: @Alex What if he were a Levi?