# Can Moshiach be a woman?

Tags: women, messiah

Is there any statement by chazal or the poskim which precludes Moshiach from being a woman?

Comment: I don't think this would suffice as a direct answer, but see R Nahman here, as well as Rashi on what he says. http://www.dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=megilah&daf=14b&go=Go

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37570
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10599
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26938
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22271
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22814
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8857
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13359
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37585
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35312
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37449
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35296

Answer (score 29):

Rambam Hilchos Malachim perek 1 Halacha 5

"אין מעמידין אשה במלכות שנאמר עליך מלך ולא מלכה וכן כל משימות שבישראל אין ממנים בהם אלא איש."

women cannot become kings.

Also when the gemara discusses Mashiach they use the loshon "him" and Ben Dovid see Sanhedrin 98

Comment: However there were female "kings" in the past (eg [Melachim II 11](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt09b11.htm#3)). Your last sentence is of course irrelevant, since male pronouns are the default gender neutral option in Hebrew

Comment: @DoubleAA your really bringing a proof from Atalya?!

Comment: I really am. It's a proof that a women "king" has a chalot "king".

Comment: @DoubleAA, Jeremia only tells us that she staged a bloddy coup and prolonged her reign of terror for 6 years. Do you have a source that calls her a king? Or that says she has a 'chalot king', as you say?

Comment: @BabySeal Jeremiah says מלכת. Sounds like a king, no? He could have said משלת or רדה

Comment: @DoubleAA affirmative

Comment: @sam never mind Atalyah, how 'bout Salome Alexandra(Shelamzion in the DSS), Alexander Janneus' widow, mother of Aristobulus and John Hyrcanus II, and Queen for around a decade? Some info here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salome_Alexandra

Comment: http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt25a07.htm#18

Answer (score 2):

In the question as posed it is not clear which of the 2 messiahs are under discussion. After a perusal of several sources I have not seen any statement from the sages of the talmud that Moshiach "ben" Yosef (Sukka 52a-b) needs to be male and cannot be female. Unlike Moshiach Ben David who is to have the status of a king and therefore according to halahic authorities such as Rambam is precluded from being a woman, Moshiach ben Yosef (MbY) does not seem to be viewed as a king but rather as a warrior.

Broadly speaking the term Moshiach (anointed) can be applied to persons who were not anointed with the [שמן המשחה](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%9F_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%97%D7%94) such as gentile Cyrus of Persia (Isaiah 45:1) and therefore need not imply MbY is actually anointed (implying kingship). Since MbY is by definition not of the tribe of Judah it would stand to reason this person will not be inaugurated as a king.

In terms of Poskim/Responsa - Rav Hai Gaon does mention MbY (Otzar Hageonim p.387) but does not comment on gender.

Comment: H. Melakhim 1:5 doesn't only apply to kings, but any position of authority  אין מעמידין אישה במלכות--שנאמר "מלך" (דברים יז,טו), ולא מלכה; **וכן כל משימות שבישראל, אין ממנים בהם אלא איש.** Presumably a military leader that commands troops would be precluded (which is what MbY sounds like). What do you do with that Rambam?

Comment: What do you do with the distinctly gendered language of "ben"? Are there other occasions where you see a specific woman called the "son" of someone?

Comment: Cyrus of Persia was in fact a king... so not the strongest counter evidence of other usages of משיח

Comment: "Since MbY is by definition not of the tribe of Judah it would stand to reason this person will not be inaugurated as a king" There were non-Judahite/Davidic kings that were however accepted as king (e.g. the Hasmoneans). It's not the ideal, but it happens.

Comment: @Deuteronomy thank you for the important comments. To my mind, the discussion of whether women can serve as military leaders is certainly relevant if this were an appointed position rather than an assumed one.

Comment: There are quite a few sources (including the R. Saadia Gaon) that refer to MbY as מלך משיח בן יוסף (the King Messiah, son of Joseph). They see him as a king, in which case this position would be subject to the same considerations as MbY (i.e. only a male king may be appointed).

Comment: @Deuteronomy I'm not aware of those sources, but perhaps that would make for a great answer for you to post

Comment: personally I think peshat in the OP is that the Q concerned MbD (which is who the vast majority are referring to when they say "Moshiach") but insofar as you took the opportunity to answer about MbY, I felt it only proper to point out the flaws in your answer. Having done so, it seems like overkill to offer an entirely new answer here.

Comment: If you're curious though, see [here](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%94%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%95%D7%94%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8_%D7%97/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7_%D7%94) and [here](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%99%22%D7%9D_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%94_%D7%94) for a couple of sources that refer to MbY as king.