# Does Moshiach have to be a king?

Tags: messiah, malchut-royalty, messianic-redemption

Partially based on [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35296/can-moshiach-be-a-woman), I would like to know what the source is that Moshiach will be a king.

Comment: This question would be much more meaningful if you'd include information about what "Moshiach" is, and what your source is that there will be such a thing. One valid way to read the question at present is "What is the source that the future king of Israel will be a king?"

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37570
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10599
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26938
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22271
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22814
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8857
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13359
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37585
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35312
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37449
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35296

Answer (score 10):

Well, I guess we can start with Zecharia [9:9](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16213/jewish/Chapter-9.htm#showrashi=true&v=9)

> גִּילִי מְאֹד בַּת צִיּוֹן הָרִיעִי בַּת יְרוּשָׁלִַם הִנֵּה מַלְכֵּךְ יָבוֹא לָךְ צַדִּיק וְנוֹשָׁע הוּא עָנִי וְרֹכֵב עַל חֲמוֹר וְעַל עַיִר בֶּן אֲתֹנוֹת
>
> Be exceedingly happy, O daughter of Zion; Shout, O daughter of Jerusalem. Behold! Your king shall come to you. He is just and victorious; humble, and riding a donkey and a foal, the offspring of [one of] she-donkeys.

Rashi there says it references Moshiach, as does the Gemara in Sanhedrin 79a (specifically using this verse to reject an opinion that the Messianic era will come without a king).

The Rambam paskens this way as well. In fact, he includes it as part of his 13 principles of faith. A messianic era means a king leading the world to follow Hashem's Torah.

Answer (score 1):

The Messiah will be a **KING**, who will reinstate the Kingdom of the house of David ([Rambam, Yad, Hilchos Melachim 11:1](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188356/jewish/Melachim-uMilchamot-Chapter-11.htm)).

**הַמֶּלֶךְ הַמָּשִׁיחַ עָתִיד לַעֲמֹד וּלְהַחְזִיר מַלכוּת דָּוִד לְיָשְׁנָהּ לַמֶּמְשָׁלָה הָרִאשׁוֹנָה.**