# Will Moshiach know that he is Moshiach?

Tags: messiah

I am not asking how I will know who Moshiach is.  My question is how will he know to do those things which will let me know who he is.  And specifically, will he know long before his revelation that he is Moshiach (i.e. is it possible some guy is walking around for 20 years knowing that he is Moshiach but can't tell anyone yet) or will he suddenly get a nevuah to go do all those things Moshiach does so well?

As always, please source your answers.

(No, I'm not wondering if I may be Moshiach and just don't know it - I am definitively not of the Davidic line.  But maybe you?)

Comment: Midrash/gemara says Josiah could have been moshiach. maybe relevant.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37570
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10599
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26938
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22271
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22814
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8857
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13359
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37585
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35312
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37449
http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35296

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44031

Comment: @BabySeal Impressive sourcing. You do realize that one of your links takes us back to this question, right?

Comment: @Shokhet LOL oops! http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2044/4682

Comment: Not sure how you know you are not of Davidic lineage, unless you are a kohen or Levi. Even then, it is not certain as we generally assume that we don't have "kohanim meyuchasim" these days. That is, we cannot be absolutely sure that kohanim are truly kohanim.

Comment: "how will he know to do those things..." Maybe he will do them on his own accord...

Comment: @mevaqesh geirim and their descendants know pretty well...

Comment: @yEz what are you responding to?

Comment: @mevaqesh to how someone knows they are not of Davidic lineage, despite being neither a Kohen nor a Levi.

Comment: @yEz but assuming that the Davidic lineage is patrilineal, while necessity for conversion is matrilineal, I see no obviously compelling evidence that the two are mutually exclusive. BTW you have not resoponded to my primary point that you assume that Messiah will not perform his notable activities based on his own inspiration. Do you have any evidence to back up this assumption?

Comment: @mevaqesh If one's self or father is a convert, one is not a patrilineal descendant of the Davidic line, and kingship follows patrilineal descent. My assumptions are based on what seems reasonable to me - one would not start fighting wars (Rambam melachim 11:4) based on his "own inspiration." Also, if he is supposed to be awaiting Moshiach's arrival until such time as he comes (melachim 12:2), will he know to stop waiting and start being Moshiach without being told to violate this precept? IAE, I don't need to substantiate my assumptions to ask - if you can refute them, post an answer doing so

Comment: @yEz "If one's self or father is a convert, one is not a patrilineal descendant of the Davidic line, and kingship follows patrilineal descent." evidence that patrilineal descent sans matrilineal descent would not suffice? (not: I do not think your assumption is unlikely; I just want to make sure we are dealing with a not unlikely assumption, rather than a fact.

Comment: You think prophets would not know they are prophets? Does God know he is the God?  This is an insult to the divine Messiah. He will come soon the second time. You should focus on whether do you know him.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Chatam Sofer in his responsa section 6:98 (collected answers) states explicitly that Moshiach will not know that he is Moshiach until the time for the redemption is at hand.

> והנה בהא דביאת בן דוד , צריך אני
>   להציע הוצעה אחת והוא, כמו שהיה משה רבינו
>   ע"ה שהיה הגואל הראשון נזדקן שמונים שנה ולא
>   ידע ולא הרגיש בעצמו שהוא יהיה גואל ישראל,
>   ואפילו כשאמר לו הקב"ה לכה ואשלחך אל פרעה
>   (שמות ג ' י') מכל מקום סירב ולא רצה לקבל על
>   עצמו, "כן יהיה אי"ה הגואל האחרון

Comment: This is also what is brought from Sefer Ohr HaChamah of Rabbi Avraham Azulai to Zohar, parshat Shemot 7b quoting Rabbi Chaim Vital.  http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21490&st=&pgnum=19&hilite=

Comment: According to what is taught by Rabbi Chaim Vital, Moshiach will become aware that he is Moshiach at the time that he merits to prophecy. This is like Moshe Rabbeinu. To emphasize, tradition teaches that the level of prophecy of Moshiach will rival, but not be as great as Moshe. Since part of the quantification of Moshe's level is how quickly he attained prophecy, it means Moshiach will attain this similar level at or slightly after the time Moshe did. Moshe achieved this when he was 80 years old.

Comment: Um, can you translate it in English?

Comment: @yaacov Deane "part of the quantification of Moshe's level is how quickly he attained prophecy"  Sources?

Comment: @Orion We are discussing the level of prophecy related to when Moshe knew for a certainty that he was the redeemer of the Jewish people. That source is in the five books of Moshe discussing when G-d first appeared to him at the burning bush. That was when Moshe was 80 years old.

Comment: @yaacov Deane I'm not asking for a source of when or how fast Moshe recieved prophecy. I'm wondering how you know that Mishiach being almost as great as Moshe means he attains prophecy almost as quickly as Moshe and not just that the clarity/strength of his prophecy will be almost as great.

Comment: @Orion That is a general principle about the final redemption that was taught in great detail by the Lubavitcher Rebbe in explaining the posuk from Micah 7:15. See also Rabbeinu Bechya to BeMidbar 15:41:2

Answer (score 6):

Well seeming from the pashut pshat(some may not agree) in the Gemara Sanhedrin 98 which discusses the story of Eliyahu Hanavi and Reb Yehoshua Ben Levi ,where he asked when is Mashiach coming,and Eliyahu answered go ask him yourself and he went to Rome and asked Mashiach himself. See there for more details.

From here it seems clear that Mashiach knows who he is .

Comment: but he wasn't so i dont think you can take the story too literally

Comment: I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: he wasn't the actual mashiach

Comment: @ray He could have been for that generation that didn't merit to bring him...

Comment: Beautiful answer. The Chatam Sofer's logic in my opinion seems kind of wishy-washy in the sense that it relies upon us knowing all the details of Moses' life. Yet he was one of the [Lamed Vav Tzadikim](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/837699/jewish/Who-Are-the-36-Hidden-Tzadikim.htm) which  if one of them comes to a realization of their true purpose, [they would never admit it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tzadikim_Nistarim#Their_purpose). You'd think after Moses used the Shem HaMeforash to kill the Egptyian that it would have foreshadowed his purpose, or some time along the way.

Answer (score 4):

This would probably depend on which approach one takes to how the coming of the Messiah is supposed to unfold. According to [Rambam, Hilchot Melachim uMilchamot 11](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/e511.htm), the process will unfold naturally, without any supernatural events. The Rambam even metions in Halacha 8 that there will be a period of time in which, based on his accomplishments, we may assume that he is the Messiah, and then if he continues that will confirm to us that he is the Messiah. All this would seem to indicate that, being that this is a completely non-supernatural process occuring, that the Messiah would be in the same position as us as to whether or not he is actually the Messiah.

However, if you take the approach of Ramban and others of a more Kabbalistic persuasion that the coming of the Messiah will be a supernaturalistic event, that the Messiah himself will preform miracles and the like and will have the qualities of a prophet, presumably he will be told prophetically that he is indeed the Messiah.

Comment: The Rambam also says that Moshiach will be a prophet.