# moshiach, arrival and the torah's perspective

Tags: messiah

I know someone who has a shirt is in his closet which he designated for himself to wear when *Moshiach* comes.

1. How will we know when the *yeshuah* of *HaKadosh Baruch Hu* - in which he will bring *Moshiach* - has really come?
2. Will we be prepared beforehand for his arrival or will he come in the blink of an eye or both?
3. Will there be some type of noise that will determine that he has come or will our souls be able to sense it before our physical ears and eyes?

Comment: The Rambam discuses yemos haMashiach ,however I believe he mentions no one will know exactly until it happens

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37585